# Unknown constant tag 79 in class file org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils

Tags: java, spring

At the [Official Spring Quick Start](https://spring.io/quickstart), the step#2 publishes a *Hello World* demo.
When I run this piece of code, it outputs this error:

> Unknown constant tag 79 in class file
> org/springframework/core/annotation/AnnotationUtils

Run on Ubuntu 20.

1. I generated this project with the latest release of Spring today.
2. I copied that piece of code.
3. I run the following command:

> ./mvnw spring-boot:run

as it is told by them.

What's wrong?
UPDATED:
[GIST](https://gist.github.com/abelardolg/60c6d2dcbf56bc304e53093f1b2b9f8f)

Best regards.

Comment: Post your full stacktrace,

Comment: Can you post your pom.xml?

Comment: I generated a public gist. Please, see the uptaded post. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I do some research on the "java.lang.ClassFormatError: Unknown constant tag ..." error and it seems an error on the loaded class file. I suggest you re-download at least the spring-core 2.3.7.RELEASE. Remove the cached jar at $HOME/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/2.3.7.RELEASE and rerun the maven command.

Comment: There we go! Thanks.

Comment: I haven't found that 2.3.7.RELEASE folder under spring-core.
I have 5.2.12.RELEASE and 5.3.2 after I downloaded the v2.4.1 of SpringBoot.
I am going to delete them and restart this setting.

Comment: I have delete the spring framework folder under $HOME/.m2/repository/org folder and it works.
Thanks to everyone!